# Out of bounds UIView constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a cake of 3 UIView layers with programmatically constraints.

Constructed function for programmatically set up constraints:

```
func setupViewConstraints(item:UIView, leadingTo:NSLayoutXAxisAnchor, leadingCon:CGFloat, 
trailingTo:NSLayoutXAxisAnchor, trailingCon:CGFloat, topTo:NSLayoutYAxisAnchor, 
topCon:CGFloat, bottomTo:NSLayoutYAxisAnchor, bottomCon:CGFloat) {
    item.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    item.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingTo, constant: leadingCon).isActive = true
    item.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingTo, constant: trailingCon).isActive = true
    item.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topTo, constant:topCon).isActive = true
    item.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomTo, constant:bottomCon).isActive = true
}
```

The lowest base layer is lightGray.

```
view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
```

The 2nd layer contains 2 `UIView` (red and blue) with constraints .

```
let red = UIView()
red.backgroundColor = .red
view.addSubview(red)
setupViewConstraints(item: red, leadingTo: view.leadingAnchor, leadingCon: 0, trailingTo: view.trailingAnchor, trailingCon: -(view.frame.width)*0.2), topTo: view.topAnchor, topCon: 0, bottomTo: view.bottomAnchor, bottomCon: -(view.frame.width)*0.8)

let blue = UIView()
blue.backgroundColor = .blue
view.addSubview(blue)
setupViewConstraints(item: blue, leadingTo: view.leadingAnchor, leadingCon: 0, trailingTo: view.trailingAnchor, trailingCon: -(view.frame.width)*0.2), topTo: red.bottomAnchor, topCon: 0, bottomTo: view.bottomAnchor, bottomCon: 0)
```

[image: 3 UIView]

And on top i have yellow `UIView` layer, which overlaps all the lower layers.

```
let yellow = UIView()
yellow.backgroundColor = .yellow
view.addSubview(yellow)
setupViewConstraints(item: yellow, leadingTo: view.leadingAnchor, leadingCon: 0, trailingTo: view.trailingAnchor, trailingCon: 0, topTo: view.topAnchor, topCon: 0, bottomTo: view.bottomAnchor, bottomCon: 0)
```

Also, i have `UINavigationBar` with `UINavigationItem` inside the yellow `UIView`.

```
//Add navigation item and buttons
        naviItem = UINavigationItem()
        naviItem.setRightBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.add, target:self, action:#selector(goToDestVC)), animated: true)
        naviItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "hamburger_slim_30"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(hamburgerBtnPressed)), animated: true)

        //Add navigation bar with transparent background
        naviBar = UINavigationBar()
        naviBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        naviBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        naviBar.isTranslucent = true

// Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
        naviBar.items = [naviItem]

        view.addSubview(naviBar)
        setupViewConstraints(item: naviBar, leadingTo: yellow.leadingAnchor, leadingCon: 0, trailingTo: yellow.trailingAnchor, trailingCon: 0, topTo: yellow.topAnchor, topCon: 0, bottomTo: yellow.bottomAnchor, bottomCon: -(view.frame.height)*0.9))
```

[image: Top UIView layer with UINavigationBar]

And i have `hamburgerBtnPressed` function, which should shift the yellow layer to the right by 80% (I change the values of leading and trailing constants by 80%), **but this does not work!!!**

```
var hamburgerMenuIsVisible = false

    @objc func hamburgerBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if !hamburgerMenuIsVisible {

            let menuWidth = (self.view.frame.width)*0.8

              setupViewConstraints(item: layoutView, leadingTo: view.leadingAnchor, leadingCon: menuWidth, trailingTo: view.trailingAnchor, trailingCon: menuWidth, topTo: view.topAnchor, topCon: 0, bottomTo: view.bottomAnchor, bottomCon: 0)

            hamburgerMenuIsVisible = true

        } else {

            setupViewConstraints(item: layoutView, leadingTo: view.leadingAnchor, leadingCon: 0, trailingTo: view.trailingAnchor, trailingCon: 0, topTo: view.topAnchor, topCon: 0, bottomTo: view.bottomAnchor, bottomCon: 0)

            hamburgerMenuIsVisible = false
        }

        // layoutIfNeeded() lays out the subviews immediately and forces the layout before drawing
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay:0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }) { (animationComplete) in
            print("Animation is complete!")
        }
    }
```

But if I change the values of leading and trailing constants to negative, everything will work, and the menu will shift to the left without any problems.

```
let menuWidth = -(self.view.frame.width)*0.8
```

[image: To the left]

Please explain.. what's the issue? Why the yellow `UIView` shifted to the left with negative values of constraints, and does not work with positive values of constraints?  and gives an error:

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002853c0 UIView:0x7fa947c35850.trailing == UIView:0x7fa947e1d2d0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000092750 UIView:0x7fa947c35850.trailing == UIView:0x7fa947e1d2d0.trailing + 331.2   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000092750 UIView:0x7fa947c35850.trailing == UIView:0x7fa947e1d2d0.trailing + 331.2   (active)>
```

---

**Update:** I have choose **Option 2**:
Keep a reference to the constraint that you want to change and just adjust its constant. Need to call setNeedsLayout too before layoutIfNeeded.

Updated code:

```
var leadingC: NSLayoutConstraint!
var trailingC: NSLayoutConstraint!
var yellow: UIView!
```

loadView():

```
    yellow = UIView()
        yellow.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.addSubview(yellow)

        //Set up leading and trailing constraints for handling yellow view shift
        leadingC = yellow.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
        trailingC = yellow.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)

//Put leadingC.constant and trailingC.constant into the function
        setupViewConstraints(item: yellow, leadingTo: view.leadingAnchor, leadingCon: leadingC!.constant, trailingTo: view.trailingAnchor, trailingCon: trailingC.constant, topTo: view.topAnchor, topCon: 0, bottomTo: view.bottomAnchor, bottomCon: 0)
```

Updated Hamburger function:

```
 @objc func hamburgerBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if !hamburgerMenuIsVisible {

            let menuWidth = (self.view.frame.width)*0.8


            leadingC!.constant = menuWidth
            trailingC!.constant = menuWidth

            print(leadingC.constant, trailingC.constant)

            hamburgerMenuIsVisible = true

        } else {

            leadingC!.constant = 0
            trailingC!.constant = 0


            hamburgerMenuIsVisible = false
        }

        // layoutIfNeeded() lays out the subviews immediately and forces the layout before drawing
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay:0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {

            self.view.setNeedsLayout()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }) { (animationComplete) in
            print("Animation is complete!")
        }
    }
    var hamburgerMenuIsVisible = false
```

I have no errors and "Animation complete!" was printed too, but nothing happens on the screen, no animation.

[image: Output]

Comment: This is one reason I personally do not *combine* constraint creation into a generic function - too hard to decipher. First, if I read you correctly, there's *no* problem with red, blue, and gray views, right? If so, please remove them from your question as it makes for noise. Are you trying to compute 80% of a frame in order to (a) move or (b) shrink the yellow view? Because in the former, you've already said it works - because you are moving leading/trailing anchors. But if you want the latter, you need to change the width anchor - which I'm not seeing in your generic function.

Comment: I want to shift yellow UIView to the right for 80%, in order to (a) move yellow view.
I'm using trailing anchor for "width", and I can set only width OR trailing anchor, otherwise going to get conflicts.

Comment: Correct. So it sounds like you want a *static* width. That's part of the confusion... (1) Why are you computing 80% of a frame width? That doesn't change. More, (2) to keep this *static* width you alter the constants - possibly it will work with the multipliers but I think not - of the leading *and* trailing by a negative value to shift/move left and back to their original value to shift right. I thought that's what you said worked? What am I missing?

Comment: I'm computing 80% of frame width, because it's a width of 2nd layer menu , if the yellow view shifts to the left for 80%, it's opens hidden menu. 
The width can be any, the question is not about that. 
In this case default value of leading and trailing constant is equal to 0, i change the values by the same amount, in this case (.trailing/leading + 331.2 (80% of the view width)) and the yellow view must shift to the right. -->leading+331.2 -->trailing+331.2. With negative values it's works, and shift the yellow view to the left, but doesn't works with positive values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it needs negative values because the constraints need to be set up  in the correct direction. Change this and you can remove all of those negative constants:

```
item.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingTo, constant: leadingCon).isActive = true
item.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingTo, constant: trailingCon).isActive = true
item.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topTo, constant:topCon).isActive = true
item.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomTo, constant:bottomCon).isActive = true
```

to

```
item.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingTo, constant: leadingCon).isActive = true
trailingTo.constraint(equalTo: item.trailingAnchor, constant: trailingCon).isActive = true
item.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topTo, constant:topCon).isActive = true
bottomTo.constraint(equalTo: item.bottomAnchor, constant:bottomCon).isActive = true
```

Secondly, every time you call `setupViewConstraints` you are creating and activating another set of constraints.

Option 1:

Remove all constraints for the yellow view before setting them up again.

Option 2:

Keep a reference to the constraint that you want to change and just adjust its constant. You may need to call `setNeedsLayout` too before `layoutIfNeeded`.

Option 3:

Add 2 contraints. The initial leading constraint, and one with the width you desire. Change the priority of the first constraint to `999` (default is `1000`) and toggle the `isActive` property of the other when you want to show/hide the menu.

```
let leading = yellow.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
leading.priority = UILayoutPriority(999)
leading.isActive = true

let otherConstraint = yellow.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: (view.frame.width)*0.8)
otherConstraint.isActive = false // toggle this property to show/hide
```

Option 2 is probably going to be the best for performance. From the apple docs:

> Setting the constant on an existing constraint performs much better
>   than removing the constraint and adding a new one that's exactly like
>   the old except that it has a different constant

Comment: Thanks. I have choose Option 2 (please check the update), and I have no errors, "Animation complete!" was printed in outputs, but nothing happens on the screen, no animation. What is the reason?

Comment: It looks like you need to call isActive in the animation block.

Comment: How can i call it in the animation block? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Ignore me. I looked at option 3. [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/seanhenry/ecc62180924217749a84f948ae8bd8c8) I used to get it to work. Create a new playground in Xcode and replace the contents with this. The animation is on a timer so you should see it animate open and closed.